# .NET MAUI ApplePay, GooglePay + Stripe

Tags: .net, xamarin, maui, applepay, google-pay

I want to implement payments in my .net MAUI mobile application using GooglePay and ApplePay through Stripe payment system, however it is extremely hard to find needed information on how to do that, expecially there is no complete guide on how to implement such things.

Did someone had experience with such things? Could you please describe general pipeline on what I need to implement payments, how it is different from payments implemented on web? Maybe someone has some code examples or any other usefull materials

No information found.

Comment: Have you got any result about this?

Comment: Fortunately yes, I found needed articles for xamarin and it works good on MAUI
[link](https://www.mindfiretechnology.com/blog/archive/google-pay-stripe-xamarin)
[link](https://www.mindfiretechnology.com/blog/archive/apple-pay-stripe-xamarin)

Comment: Thank you for replying , I have found these articles but my problem is that I couldn't find the package Stripe.iOS. please can you send me the project page of the package and it will be great if you clarify how you implement it

Comment: Actually I used different payment system, local for my country, so unfortunately can't help you with Stripe.iOS. Although we got payment UI to be shown on iOS as well as on Android

Comment: I think you can try to use Stripe library for .Net and call api methods in more direct way than using Stripe.iOS

Comment: Have you already got Stripe payments working, without Apple/Google Pay?  If so, are you creating a payment session/intent and opening a webview for the user to pay, or some other way (e.g. Elements, etc.)?

Comment: I used Stripe payments before by creating payment session hovewer it was browser implementation so unfortunately I don't know possible ways of implementing Stripe payments on mobile without Apple/Google Pay. It seems to me that payment session/intent and opening a webview is a good way

Answer (score 1):

Finally I get the best solution
I have created an IOS binding library for IOS Stripe following this walkthrough
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-swift/walkthrough#prerequisites
and created my needed code form stripe
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart?platform=ios

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you please attach some code samples if you have time for that. That would econom a lot of time for those who does at the first time